# Kafka triggered lambda with a message sent from another lambda in LocalstackPro

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-lambda, java-17, localstack

I’ve been working a while with LocalStackPro and now I’m facing a problem for which I haven’t been able to find a solution.

I have a series of lambda functions that triggers when receiving a Kafka message. When I create one lambda, the cluster and the eventmap for it for a certain topic, it triggers as it should. This happens with all my lambdas.

The problem is that some of these functions, send a message to another Kafka topic, and this message is the trigger for the next lambda (which I have already linked with the eventmapping). However, when I upload and link all lambdas to their topics, only the first one uploaded and linked works, the rest does not trigger, nor with the output message of the original lambda nor when writing a message directly in their topic (as I said, when tested individually, all of them work properly), nonetheless if I use the “invoke” with the properly payload, they work as expected.

I’m using latest localstackpro image.

Someone knows what could be happenning here? Has anyone faced a similar issue? I'm quite sure it is not a code problem, my best guess is that it is related with the localstack kafka configuration, but I haven't been able to find a way.

Ways I've tried :

- I've tried creating one cluster with several topics and linking each one to the lambdas.
- I've tried crreating different kafka clusters for each function with its correspondent topic, modifying the timeout and memory size of the lambdas.
- Creating everything via CLI and via web interface.

Thanks!